# How to define Loopback project as production environment?

Tags: angularjs, production, loopback

How can I change my loopback project in to production environment?

I'm using AngularJs SDK in this project.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Preparing-for-deployment.html

Everything is explained in this loopback documentation.

---

What I'm using for production is `dotenv` npm module.
Then in the `server.js` file require the module

`require('dotenv').config();`

Now create `.env` file in the main folder and add the following content

```
NODE_ENV=production
```

NODE_ENV is environment variable that loopback looks for. Now create files like `config.production.js`, `datasources.production.js` and so on.. with production values.

Hope this helped

Comment: I saw that guide but it doesn't help me. I still don't know how to define the environment to "production"

Answer (score 0):

**1. Create component-config.production.json in /server directory**

```
    {
  "loopback-component-explorer": null
    }
```

**2. Create config.production.json in /server directory**

It should be the same as development (default config) but you can change port/host and your custom options

**Example :**

```
    {
      "restApiRoot": "/api",
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 8080,
      "remoting": {
        "context": false,
        "rest": {
          "handleErrors": false,
          "normalizeHttpPath": false,
          "xml": false
        },
        "json": {
          "strict": false,
          "limit": "100kb"
        },
        "urlencoded": {
          "extended": true,
          "limit": "100kb"
        },
        "cors": false
      }
    }
```

**3. Create datasources.production.json in /server directory**

Also its the same as development datasource file only if you have different database from production or credentials user/password

**Example :**

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "MongoDBs": {
    "host": "mongo",
    "port": 27017,
    "url": "",
    "database": "middleware",
    "password": "",
    "name": "MongoDBs",
    "allowExtendedOperators": true,
    "user": "",
    "connector": "mongodb"
  }
}
```

**PS : You don't need middleware Production you can read about it [here](https://github.com/strongloop/strong-error-handler) in Migration from old LoopBack error handler section 5. point.**

**4. Set your node environment**

If you are a :

**windows** user >

Add in this line in your console : `SET NODE_ENV=production` then node . (or nodemon if installed).

**Linux or MacOS** user >

Add in this line in your terminal : `export MY_CUSTOM_VAR="production"` then node . (or nodemon if installed).

**5. For more Info about Environment-specific configuration check the official documentation [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Environment-specific-configuration.html). (same for lb2 & lb3)**